# how to validate texbox with plus minus valus angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I need to enter plus minus values in the textbox. I did below validation using angular js.
But when user enter zero, user can be enter it without plus or minus symbol.
in my solution user can not enter zero without plus or minus symbol. 
how to allow type zero without plus or minus symbol.

```
<input name="temperature" type="text" class="form-control" ng-maxlength="3"
 ng-model="eletctyDetail.temperatureValue" ng-required="true" 
 ng-pattern="/^[-+]\d+(\.\d+)?$/" ng-pattern-err-type="tempPattern" />
```

Comment: Why did you accept a solution that does not work? Look, if you do not want to allow users enter a `0` with `+` or `-` in front, use [`/^(0|[+-][1-9])\d*(\.\d+)?$/`](https://jsfiddle.net/kkjhujhb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern - `/^[-+]\d+(\.\d+)?$/` - matches a `-` or `+` at the start position obligatorily. Then, `\d+` matches *any* one or more digits.

Now, you need to only match a `0` or `+/-` followed with any digits from `1` to `9` range after it. That is where you need to use alternation: `(0|[-+][1-9])`.

The whole regex will  look like

```
ng-pattern="/^(0|[+-][1-9])\d*(\.\d+)?$/"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hKWoaa/1).

If you need to make `-` / `+` optional use

```
ng-pattern="/^(0|[+-]?[1-9])\d*(\.\d+)?$/"
                     ^
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(0|[+-][1-9])` - a `0` or `+`/`-` followed with a digit from `1` to `9` range (so, `-` or `+` is obligatory only in front of `1-9`) (NOTE: if you use `[-+]?`, the plus or minus will become optional since `?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences)
- `\d*(\.\d+)?` - 0+ digits (note the `+` in your pattern becomes `*`, since the first digit is already consumed with an alternation group), followed with an optional sequence of a `.` + 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I have modified the explanation a bit due to a typo. See "so, `-` or `+` is obligatory only in front of *`1-9`) (NOTE: if you use `[-+]?`, the plus or minus will become optional since `?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences)*"

Answer (score 1):

What about this one

```
<input name="temperature" type="text" class="form-control" ng-maxlength="3"
 ng-model="eletctyDetail.temperatureValue" ng-required="true" 
 ng-pattern="^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$" ng-pattern-err-type="tempPattern" />
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/votmo7zh/)

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: numbers must enter with plus or minus symbol. but zero can be enter without +,-. can u help me sir.

Comment: my ng-pattern is ok. but problem is , user can not enter '0' without +,- symbol.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Azanka/pm1xv93s/1/

Pls check . when user enter '0', it must be true. (0 should be allow without + or -). thanks

Comment: use /^[-+]\d+(\.\d+)?$|^0/

Comment: use /^[-+][1-9]+(\.[1-9]+)?$|^[0]/